# Cross compiling boost for android using conan

Tags: android, c++, boost, cmake, conan

I was trying to cross compile some conan libraries using android ndk from my linux machine.
When trying to cross compile boost i get build failure error. Other conan packages cross compile perfectly  except boost. I have added the conan profile and err log.

**My conan profile:**

```
include(default)
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=clang
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=12
os=Android
os.api_level=21
[build_requires]
[options]
[env]
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/local/Downloads/android-ndk-r23
```

```
    WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '$(>) > $(<)' in '/home/local/.conan            /data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/libs/stacktrace/build/Jamfile.v2' file.
    WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '/* thread_local */' in '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/boost/stacktrace/detail/libbacktrace_impls.hpp' file.
    WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '/* static __thread */' in '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/boost/stacktrace/detail/libbacktrace_impls.hpp' file.
    boost/1.76.0: WARN: Patching user-config.jam
    boost/1.76.0: WARN: 
    using zlib : 1.2.11 : <include>"/home/local/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/18bbcddf275ee23aa172cdc6dbfa549e2411acfd/include" <search>"/home/local/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/18bbcddf275ee23aa172cdc6dbfa549e2411acfd/lib" <name>z ;
    using bzip2 : 1.0.8 : <include>"/home/local/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/_/_/package/a765640a31d963ba8d5612cab2f1811597d3de80/include" <search>"/home/local/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/_/_/package/a765640a31d963ba8d5612cab2f1811597d3de80/lib" <name>bz2 ;
    using "clang-linux" :  :   : 
    <compileflags>"-I/home/local/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/package/18bbcddf275ee23aa172cdc6dbfa549e2411acfd/include" <linkflags>"-L/home/local/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/package/18bbcddf275ee23aa172cdc6dbfa549e2411acfd/lib"  ;
    boost/1.76.0: Cross building, detecting compiler...
    boost/1.76.0: Cross building flags: []
    boost/1.76.0: WARN: b2 -q numa=on target-os=android architecture=arm address-model=64 binary-format=elf abi=aapcs --layout=system --user-config=/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/user-config.jam -sNO_ZLIB=0 -sNO_BZIP2=0 -sNO_LZMA=1 -sNO_ZSTD=1 boost.locale.icu=off --disable-icu boost.locale.iconv=on boost.locale.iconv.lib=libc threading=multi visibility=hidden link=static variant=release --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-container --with-context --with-contract --with-coroutine --with-date_time --with-exception --with-fiber --with-filesystem --with-graph --with-iostreams --with-json --with-locale --with-log --with-math --with-nowide --with-program_options --with-random --with-regex --with-serialization --with-stacktrace --with-system --with-test --with-thread --with-timer --with-type_erasure --with-wave toolset=clang-linux pch=on  cxxflags="-fPIC -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_ADDR2LINE_LOCATION=/usr/bin/addr2line" install --prefix=/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/package/1e5ed3b96aff577e610fddd01bd296a709542e8c -j12 --abbreviate-paths -d0 --debug-configuration --build-dir="/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/build/1e5ed3b96aff577e610fddd01bd296a709542e8c"
    notice: found boost-build.jam at /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/boost-build.jam
    notice: loading B2 from /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/bootstrap.jam
    warning: mismatched versions of B2 engine and core
    warning: B2 engine (b2) is 4.5.0
    warning: B2 core (at /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src) is 4.4-git
    notice: Searching '/etc' '/home/local' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/util' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
    notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in '/etc' '/home/local' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/util' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/.'.
    notice: Loading explicitly specified user configuration file:
        /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/user-config.jam
    notice: Searching '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
    notice: Loading user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam' from '/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build'.
    notice: [zlib] Using pre-installed library
    notice: [zlib] Condition
    notice: [bzip2] Using pre-installed library
    notice: [bzip2] Condition
    warning: toolset clang-linux initialization: can not find tool clang++
    warning: initialized from /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/user-config.jam:5
    sh: 1: clang++: not found
    notice: will use 'clang++' for clang-linux, condition <toolset>clang-linux
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/tools/clang-linux.jam:69: in clang-linux.init
    *** argument error
    * rule clang.init-cxxstd-flags ( toolset : condition * : version )
    * called with: ( clang-linux : <toolset>clang-linux :  )
    * missing argument version
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/tools/clang.jam:54:see definition of rule 'clang.init-cxxstd-flags' being called
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1104: in using
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/user-config.jam:5: in modules.load
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:255: in load-config
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:449: in load-configuration-files
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:607: in load
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
    /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
    boost/1.76.0: 
    boost/1.76.0: ERROR: Package '1e5ed3b96aff577e610fddd01bd296a709542e8c' build failed
    boost/1.76.0: WARN: Build folder /home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/build/1e5ed3b96aff577e610fddd01bd296a709542e8c
    ERROR: boost/1.76.0: Error in build() method, line 807
            self.run(full_command, run_environment=True)
            ConanException: Error 1 while executing b2 -q numa=on target-os=android architecture=arm address-model=64 binary-format=elf abi=aapcs --layout=system --user-config=/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/source/source_subfolder/tools/build/user-config.jam -sNO_ZLIB=0 -sNO_BZIP2=0 -sNO_LZMA=1 -sNO_ZSTD=1 boost.locale.icu=off --disable-icu boost.locale.iconv=on boost.locale.iconv.lib=libc threading=multi visibility=hidden link=static variant=release --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-container --with-context --with-contract --with-coroutine --with-date_time --with-exception --with-fiber --with-filesystem --with-graph --with-iostreams --with-json --with-locale --with-log --with-math --with-nowide --with-program_options --with-random --with-regex --with-serialization --with-stacktrace --with-system --with-test --with-thread --with-timer --with-type_erasure --with-wave toolset=clang-linux pch=on  cxxflags="-fPIC -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_ADDR2LINE_LOCATION=/usr/bin/addr2line" install --prefix=/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/package/1e5ed3b96aff577e610fddd01bd296a709542e8c -j12 --abbreviate-paths -d0 --debug-configuration --build-dir="/home/local/.conan/data/boost/1.76.0/_/_/build/1e5ed3b96aff577e610fddd01bd296a709542e8c"
```

Comment: The boost package uses the native boost build system, and the recipe itself might not have support to consider Android cross-building. Probably the best would be to report to ConanCenter github repo where recipes live and community and collaborators work on this: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues